# Automation Anywhere control room device connection error

Tags: rpa

As I am using the Community Edition of Automation anywhere, I am facing the exception

> An unexpected problem occurred

while deploying the bot by accessing the device. When I check the BotRunner logs, I could find the below exception message.

> 2020-Mar-23 Mon 18:23:00.154 ERROR [qtp622707081-41] - com.automationanywhere.nodemanager.resource.RegistrationResource - unable to register java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error getting proxy credentials.

I have checked the proxy settings and the tried below things,

1. restarted the bot agent in services.msc and repeated the procedure.
2. cleared the cache and done the same
3. tried the procedure with different browser (internet explorer).

[image]

[image]

Comment: There was no screenshot...

Comment: Sorry, have added the screenshot now

Comment: @JamesZ, any idea ?

Comment: Hi, any body can answer